# Better understand Http requests parameters

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have this HttpPost Action in one of my application controllers that takes the following parameters:

```
[HttpPost]
IHttpActionResult Send(List<int> channelsIds, List<uint> destinationsIds, string content, 
                       string title, MessagePriority priority)
{
   ..
}
```

I know that usually complex objects should be sent through body and simple ones through the uri, but I have read that only one parameter can be taken from the body. If so what is the best way to handle this one?

Moreover, should I perefer to use one of these ways to pass parameters?? Is one of them better?

Edit: 
Can I join all the parameters into a single SendRequest object? How will that work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)

Comment: Looked at that, maybe you can make it clrearer for me. When I use the attribute [HttpPost] - automatically all parameters are binded and received from the request body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Asp.Net Web Api model binding](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) it will have more information than you want to know.

In your case, you should wrap up all your parameters into a single model:

```
public class SendRequest
{
    public List<int> channelsIds {get;set;}
    public List<uint> destinationsIds {get;set;}
    public string content {get;set;} 
    public string title {get;set;}
    public MessagePriority priority {get;set;}
}
```